# Why is the "mouseover" DOM event in Javascript slow when trying to play audio with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to create a feature that plays audio files on mouse enter. When I enter the a specific area, it should play the sounds, but I find it takes almost a minute to load when I use the mouseover event listener. When I use a click event, it works instantly. I was just curious on why this is the case.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!--CSS Main Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <title>Guitar App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <audio id="lowE" src="sounds/lowE.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="A" src="sounds/A.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="D" src="sounds/D.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="G" src="sounds/G.wav"></audio>
      <audio id="B" src="sounds/B.ogg"></audio>
      <audio id="highE" type="audio/ogg" src="sounds/highE.wav"></audio>
    </div>

    <div class="container"></div>
    <!--Main Script-->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## SCSS

```
$primary-color: #aa1e23;

body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  margin: 0;

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

    width: 99.7%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 2px solid $primary-color;

    .box {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: $primary-color;
    }

    .box:hover {
      transform: scale(105%);
    }
  }
}
```

## JavaScript

```
const stringSounds = ["lowE", "A", "D", "G", "B", "highE"];

stringSounds.forEach((stringSound) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("box");

  div.innerText = stringSound;

  div.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    document.querySelector(`#${stringSound}`).play();
  });

  document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(div);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to "throttle" the callback function? Meaning, preventing the callback from running multiple times.

Comment: I have tried, but I am currently stumped

Comment: My problem is, when I load the page, it takes a while before I can play the sounds when I put my cursor over an element. I've tried using preload in HTML, and a variety of different things with Javascript but I can't seem to find a fix

Comment: You may get some inspiration from here https://dev.to/thormeier/let-s-build-an-actual-working-guitar-with-javascript-bfb

Comment: Add the final HTML to your question.